# Variables count in an Object

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I have one simple question, Where we need the count of the variables in an Object:

> class cot{
>     int I;
>     int j;
>     int k;
>     }

We need the count of the variables (3) for each iteration on cot[], 
we have size() which we can use for getting size of Array List of Object.
But how to find the count of the Variables for each Iteration on the Object.

We know it is three , But need for dynamic Objects.

Comment: ... and before that re-think your design. Why do you need that? And just the number? How about their types? What about private fields? Inherited fields? And computed properties not backed by any fields?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Reflection API. Here is an example:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class cot{
    int I; int j; int k;
    String str;

    public int CountAllVariables(){
        // get reference to own class
        Class<?> clazz = this.getClass();
        // return amount of all fields
        return clazz.getDeclaredFields().length;
    }
    public int CountAllInteger(){
        int result = 0;
        // get reference to own class
        Class<?> clazz = this.getClass();
        // check all fields
        for ( Field field : clazz.getDeclaredFields() ) {
            // count if it is an int field
            if(int.class.isAssignableFrom(field.getType()))
                result++;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Now you can use it like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    cot c = new cot();
    System.out.println( c.CountAllInteger());    // prints 3
    System.out.println( c.CountAllVariables());  // prints 4
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With reflection: `MyClass.class.getFields().length`

Check [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/index.html) for more information.